# SPSiteDataQuery throwing exception while setting it's Query property

Tags: sharepoint

I am querying multiple task lists in a SharePoint site. I can retrieve the results until I set the `Query` property and specify the OrderBy clause. The detailed exception and code is pasted below. Appreciate any help

```
   private void doTasks(SPWeb currentWeb, SPSiteDataQuery q)
    {

        q.Query =
             "<OrderBy>" +
             "   <FieldRef Name='Priority' />" +
             "   <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />" +
             "</OrderBy>";


        // Specify the view fields.
        q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' Type='Text'/>";
        q.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' Type='User' Nullable='TRUE' />";
        q.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='PercentComplete' Type='Number' Nullable='TRUE'/>";
        results = currentWeb.GetSiteData(q);

        if (results.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                 //blah!
        }
    }
```

[COMException (0x80020009): 0x80020009]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +174

[SPException]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27428978
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +27812419
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery query) +521
   StoraEnso.Collaboration.WebParts.SubSiteItemAggregator.SubSiteItemAggregator.doTasks(SPWeb currentWeb, SPSiteDataQuery q) +189
   StoraEnso.Collaboration.WebParts.SubSiteItemAggregator.SubSiteItemAggregator.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +441
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +43

[WebPartException]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +19826502
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +64
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderZoneCell(HtmlTextWriter output, Boolean bMoreParts, WebPart part) +1997
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderWebParts(HtmlTextWriter output, ArrayList webParts) +508
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +1000
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +253
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +87
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the migration some page layouts were using the SPSiteDataQuery to query the ContentTypes across different webs to get the content. The code worked fine in SP2007 but in SP2010 it was throwing exception as mentioned below:

**Solution**

Make sure the field your using for the order by is included in the SPSiteDataQuery.ViewFields property. As simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `OrderBy` clause in `<Query></Query>` .

Comment: Couldn't help "The property Query contains an invalid value.". Even http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the `AssignedTo` and `PercentComplete` FieldRefs? I ask because if you are querying all lists in a site, most will not contain AssignedTo and PercentComplete fields. This can cause an error.

What is the value of `q.Lists`? If you have not set `q.Lists`, try:

```
q.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"107\" />"
```

Comment: Hi Rich, I have set the value of Lists property as you mentioned above. The query works if don't set the OrderBy clause.

Comment: According to your code above, you are setting q.Query to a string constant and then to orderBy. What is the value of orderBy?

Comment: Sorry there was mistake but the actual code is `q.Query = "<OrderBy>" + "   <FieldRef Name='Priority' />" +
             "   <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />" +
             "</OrderBy>"; `

Comment: I can't see anything else wrong. I've tried your ViewFields and OrderBy against a task list using the U2U CAML Query Builder. It worked fine. Maybe try the CAML Query Builder with your list(s) and see if that shows what is still wrong.

Comment: that's why I was also wondering. I can try other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having a similar issue: I've spent two hours before I found out that the last line of the CAML query cannot be a blank line. In other words, there must not be any line breaks at the end of the CAML query. Removing the line breaks solved the problem immediately.